# How to implement PXFormulaCombo or Formula Builder control?

Tags: acumatica

As per title. I need to customise AM207500 - Configuration Maintenance screen to add another custom field that will allow me to enter formula similar to QtyRequired field.

[image]

I got as far as displaying the correct dialog. But its missing the fields selection.

[image]

I believe I'm missing the OnRootFieldsNeeded property. But every time I try to edit the ASPX and manually add this. Its being cleared by Acumatica.

[image]

Am I in the right direction ? And how do I force this property in my ASPX ?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

A bit unconventional, but have you tried updating the ASPX page on the custom pages and then clicking on the files section to update the file? This will then ensure the file update occurs before publish and hold the configuration

Comment: I just did that - manually updated the ASPX page. I refreshed my screen and I can see the fields on the right side. However, the customisation project failed to detect the changes. So nothing changed in the project itself. Thanks for the reply !